# Vim: how to open previously opened file in split mode?

Tags: vim

Say, I opened a file named *file1.txt* present in some directory X, and after editing, I **closed** the file.
Now after sometime, I have opened another file named *file2.txt* present in some another directory Y.

Now How to open the *file1.txt* using `vsplit` if I can't remember the directory X. Is there a way?

Comment: Here is [one way](https://github.com/yegappan/mru).

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
:sbp
```

or

```
:sbprevious
```

This means *split and edit previous buffer*.  It will split the current buffer horizontally and open the previously edited file in the top buffer.

The full command allows you to jump back to the `N`th previous buffer:

```
:Nsbp
```

or

```
:sbp N
```

If you are unsure of how many "files ago" you edited that other file, you may then use

```
:bp
```

repeatedly until you get back to the file you once edited (if you have edited many files in-between during the same session).

This only work within one `vim` session.

Answer (score 0):

Did you close Vim when you closed *file1.txt*?

**Below will work, if you didn't close Vim completely:**

If you are still in the same Window and e.g. you have *foo.txt* and another file *bar.txt* in an other split window. You could close *foo.txt* with `:wq`. Then you have the *bar.txt* still opened. Now you could open a file *baz.txt* with `:e /path/baz.txt`.
With `:bp` you could jump to the previous buffer (`:bn` to the next).
So now if you have *baz.txt* opened in your Vim you could `:vsplit` it with the previous buffer with the command `:vsplit | bp`

But if you closed Vim completely, then this solution wouldn't work.

Comment: I think OP asked more about how to open a previously opened file if he doesn't remember the path to it. Your solution still suggests to open it with an exact path `:e /path/op/doesnt/remember`. So I would not say it's a solution after all.

Comment: If you didn't close Vim, you could open a closed buffer with `:bp`, doesn't matter in which directory you are atm. In that case you could open it my way.
Say, if you have a NERDtree on the left, and file1.txt on the right, you could close file1.txt with `:wq` and then open file2.txt with NERDtree or `:e /path/file2.txt`. Then when file2.txt is open, with `vsplit | bp`it would work.
But if you closed Vim completely when you closed file1.txt, then my solution does not work.

Comment: Indeed, so I would suggest you to edit your answer highlighting important parts of it and removing irrelevant ones. Important parts here are: if OP hasn't closed `vim` completely, he can use `:vsplit | bp` to split with a previous buffer (which is actually still opened).